# one div is invisible when overlap divs

Tags: html, css

i want to make a slideshow and it should look like this.

[image]

but what i have is this . [preview](https://jsfiddle.net/ykLjy4L2/)

[image]

as you can see the problem is left side arrow [rig_arrow] is invisible and i know it's underneath of main div.i want to know how can i modify codes to visible both divs.
this is the code

html

```
  <div class="arrow" id="rig_arrow">></div>
  <div class="arrow" id="main"></div>
  <div class="arrow" id="lef_arrow"><</div>
```

css

```
.arrow{
    float:left;
}
#main{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(153,153,153);
}
#rig_arrow{

    background-color:rgb(204,204,204);
    width:20px;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
#lef_arrow{

    background-color:rgb(204,204,204);
    width:20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: this is it https://jsfiddle.net/ykLjy4L2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the divs stack on top of each other in the order they appear in the DOM. You could change the order by putting `#main` first, but then you'd need something different than just `float: left`.

Another trick to change the layer order is to use `position: relative` on the right arrow:

```
#rig_arrow{
    background-color:rgb(204,204,204);
    width:20px;
    margin-right:-20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ykLjy4L2/1/

Answer (score 1):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ykLjy4L2/3/)

No need to change your markup..Just add the below css..

Add

```
position: relative;
```

to your CSS for `#rig_arrow` and `#lef_arrow` or add these two styles to `.arrow`.